# 2 Version of jQuery Button Toggle - 1 Doesn't Work

Tags: jquery, button, toggle

So I have these two methods of creating a toggling button with a name that changes. The first one works like a charm. The second one only works after the *FIRST CLICK*. Any idea why?

**HTML:**

```
<input id="showHideButton" type="button" value="inputRead More"></input>
<button id="showHideButton" type="text" value="Read More">buttonRead More</button>
```

**Jquery:**

```
//an input that will toggle paragraph content AND change the value 
//of the button on toggle

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").click(function() {
    $("p").toggle();
    if ($(this).val() == "inputRead More") {
      $(this).val("inputRead Less");
    } else {
      $(this).val("inputRead More");
    }
  })
})

//a button that will toggle paragraph content AND
//change the value of the button on toggle

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("p").toggle();
    if ($(this).html() == "buttonRead More") {
      $(this).html("buttonRead Less");
    } else {
      $(this).html("buttonRead More");
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your code and check variables manually to make sure you are comparing the right strings.

Comment: It's [working here](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/tvexhoph/). Also note that second `</input>` should be `</button>`.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique